# Reverse proxy not working on second site block

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two site blocks in `sites-available` (which I of course created a link to `sites-enabled`). I am running express.js sites.

My first server block on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.com.conf` is a reverse proxy for `localhost:30000`

My second server block on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2.com.conf` is a reverse proxy for `localhost:30001`

For some reason, `domain2.com` shows my "Welcome to NGINX" page. `domain1.com` works just fine.

Here is my `domain2.com.conf` file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure the configuration is loaded, check `nginx -T`

Comment: So my configuration for domain2.com isn't loading at all. I made the configuration file, as stated. And even made a link in /etc/sites-enabled. So why isn't it wanting to load my configuration file?

What's even weirder is if I make a syntax error in my configuration file for domain2.com , it won't let me restart nginx without erroring out. Any idea why it isn't wanting to load my domain2.com.conf file?

Comment: I even have this in my default nginx configuration file:

 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

Which should include all configuration files under sites-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I edited /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and changed

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

to

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;
```

And that fixed the issue. The issue was that the server block for domain2.com was not loading at all.